# isometric tile tiled format javascript

Tags: javascript, tilemap, isometric, tiled

Okay im having a problem with drawing an isometric map exported from tiled. 
Here is my problem.
[image: My problem]

where it should be like this

[image: actual]

Here is the code that i used to reproduce the 1st image, what's wrong with it?

```
for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++){
            for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++){
                counter++;  
                var sprite = this.tilemap.getSprite(this.data[ counter ], this);    
                var drawX = 0, drawY = 0;


                if ( sprite ) {     
                    var cell = sprite.cell[ this.data[counter] ];   
                    if (!cell) continue;

                    if (this.orientation == 'isometric') {
                        // Isometric maps 
                        drawX = x * cell.w;
                        drawY = y * cell.h; 
                    } 


                    if (sprite && cell){
                        Engine.currentGame.ctx.drawImage(
                         sprite.sprite.img,
                         cell.x,
                         cell.y,
                         cell.w,
                         cell.h,
                         drawX, 
                         drawY,
                         cell.w,
                         cell.h
                        );
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
        game.currentGame.ctx.restore();
        return this;
    };
```

UPDATE:

```
var counter = 0;
        game.currentGame.ctx.save();
        for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++){
            for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++){
                counter++;  
                var sprite = this.tilemap.getSprite(this.data[ counter ], this);    
                var drawX = 0, drawY = 0;


                if ( sprite ) {     

                    //console.log( counter );
                    var cell = sprite.cell[ this.data[counter] ];   
                    if (!cell) continue;

                    if (this.orientation == 'isometric') {
                        // Isometric maps 
                        drawX = x * cell.w;
                        drawY = y * cell.h; 
                    } 


                    if (sprite && cell){
                        Engine.currentGame.ctx.drawImage(
                         sprite.sprite.img,
                         cell.x,
                         cell.y,
                         cell.w,
                         cell.h,
                         drawX, 
                         drawY,
                         cell.w,
                         cell.h
                        );
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
        game.currentGame.ctx.restore();
        return this;
```

[image: update]

Comment: This seems like a trivial positioning problem. What have you tried?

Comment: You need to divide by 2 for a 2:1 perspective ratio.

Comment: http://jsiso.com/tutorials/isometric-engine-basics.html
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47388/best-technique-for-drawing-isometric-tiles
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24602/javascript-isometric-draw-optimization

Ive read all of them but cant get it to work

@GerbenJacobs divide what by 2? the width and height

Comment: The position of your tiles, based on the widht and height yeah. So if you have 20x20 blocks, you need to position them on -10 on the x axis, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screens it's kinda obvious, that your tiles are positioned wrong.

So it seems your X axis needs to go from top-left to bottom-right and Y axis from top-right to bottom-left. Right now X goes from left to right and Y from top to bottom. Can you update your code to accommodate for that?

Also your spacing between the tiles is too big, but first - solve the first issue ;)

Comment: Okay I did, but now it look's very weird, ill add the new code

Comment: Your new code is the same as the old?

Comment: Na, it's not I just switched some values around like you said

Comment: So you want me to read through all of your code once again and cross-check this with the old code?

Comment: Okay i just did a bit more research and got it working!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Iso-tiled maps needs "Z-axis" work, where you must draw from the upper left, moving to the bottom right, as you already know, you must overwrite already existing tiles.

Your code right now is a basic work for common 2D tilesets.

`if (this.orientation == 'isometric') {
  // Isometric maps 
  drawX = x * (cell.w / 2);
  drawY = y * (cell.h / 2); 
}`

This should do the trick.